# Colored graph isomorphism?

Tags: networkx

I have two colored graphs. I want to determine if they are isomorphic, with the condition that the isomorphism must preserve vertex color. Is there an algorithm in `networkx` to do this?

The graphs are undirected and simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic) for `is_isomorphic`.  It takes an optional argument `nodes_match` which is a function that tests some condition on the two nodes.  It is called by `node_match(G1.node[n1], G2.node[n2])`.  So in this case, you want a function that tests whether the colors are matching.

```
import networkx as nx

def colors_match(n1_attrib,n2_attrib):
    '''returns False if either does not have a color or if the colors do not match'''
    try:
        return n1_attrib['color']==n2_attrib['color']
    except KeyError:
        return False

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, color='y')
G.add_node(2, color='b')
H=nx.Graph()
H.add_node('a', color='y')
H.add_node('b', color = 'b')
nx.is_isomorphic(G,H,node_match=colors_match)
>True
H.add_node('c', color='r')
nx.is_isomorphic(G,H,node_match=colors_match)
>False
```